# 25th and 75th percentile according to wolfram alpha

Tags: quantiles

I'm just studying my statistics exams and I came across something odd.

When I try to get the 25th or 75th percentile with wolfram alpha, it gives me another answer than I should get according to my textbooks.

simple example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=first+quartile+32%2C42%2C46%2C46%2C54

according to my textbook, the answer should actually be 37 and not 39.5

Does anyone have any idea what wolfram alpha does different?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/definition-of-quantile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are at least 9 [different definitions of empirical quantiles, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) or the [R manual (i.e., `? quantile`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/quantile.html)). R computes the 25th percentile of your data as 37 if you specify type=6 (like Minitab and SPSS)  and 39.5 if you specify type=5 (piecewise linear function):

```
> quantile(x=c(32,42,46,46,54), probs=0.25, type=5)
 25%
39.5
> quantile(x=c(32,42,46,46,54), probs=0.25, type=6)
 25%
37
```

Comment: By default, R chooses `type=7` to give a 25th percentile of 42