# Seaborn Boxplot's quartiles

Tags: quantiles, boxplot

I'm trying to understand how to properly interpret `seaborn`-generated `boxplot`s.

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
sns.boxplot(data=df)
```

When I run this code in Google Colab, the following plot appears:

[image: A Seaborn-generated boxplot]

To the best of my understanding, the y-value of the box's lower side is the data's quartile. This implies that, according to `seaborn`, the data's quartile is strictly greater than 1.5.

This doesn't align with what I know of quartiles. As far as I know, a quartile is any number `x` satisfying

```
P(X < x) <= 1/4
P(X <= x) >= 1/4
```

and, if `X` is discrete, and if `x1 < x2` are two quartiles belonging to `X`'s support, then the representative quartile is taken, by convention, to be the average of `x1` and `x2`.

Applying this to the data of the example above, this implies that the quartile should be precisely `1.5`, in contradiction to the plot, which shows the quartile to be strictly greater than `1.5`.

Comment: I don't know Python, and this question may get closed for being about code, but it looks like you made a data frame with only four values. Also, a quartile is not *any* point satifiying those conditions, it is the point at which they are satisfied. (That is a quartile is a point, not a range).  From the documentation, the Seaborn boxplot function works much like any other boxplot function.

Comment: @PeterFlom If indeed Seaborn's boxplot function works much like any other boxplot function, then I imagine you're in a position to answer my question, which I would appreciate.

Comment: Did you try out another (non-Seaborn) boxplot?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/definition-of-quantile.

Comment: Strictly the quartile here you're referring to is the lower quartile, occasionally called first quartile. In addition there is the upper quartile, and the median can also be regarded as a quartile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused more about the definition of quantiles and/or boxplots than about `seaborn` (which is mainly a wrapper for `matplotlib`).

A quantile divides a range of observations (or a probability distribution) into intervals with equal probabilities. Common quantiles include quartiles (four intervals) or percentiles (100 intervals), though you can theoretically define any quantile $p$ within $(0, 1)$.

$y$ is the **population** quantile $k$ of the variable $Y$ if:

$$\text{Pr}(Y<y)\le k\ \text{and}\ \text{Pr}(Y\le y)\ge k$$

However, we almost never observe populations, only samples. The sample quantile $p$ is defined as a weighted average of consecutive order statistics between two observations $j$ and $j+1$ from your sample $x$:

$$
Q(p)=(1-\gamma)x_j+\gamma x_{j+1}
$$

There are [nine](https://doi.org/10.2307/2684934) different common definitions of sample quantiles ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) has a summary too, and [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/05/24/definitions-sample-quantiles.html) makes some comparisons) that will determine the values of $j$ and $\gamma$ in the above formula. `seaborn` calls `numpy.percentile` to draw its boxplots which defaults to Hyndman & Fan type 7 quantiles, using the following definitions:

$$j = \lfloor np+(1-p)\rfloor$$
$$\gamma = np+(1-p)-j$$

This all seems more complicated than it needs to be right now, but with these formulae we can exactly reproduce the calculations. You have $x=\{1,2,3,4\}$ so $n=4$ and are looking for quantiles $p=0.25, 0.50, 0.75$ (quartiles). For $p=0.25$ you end up with $j=1$ and $\gamma=0.75$, so the quantile itself becomes:

$$Q(0.25)=(1-0.75)x_1+0.75x_2=0.25\times 1+0.75\times 2=1.75$$

The additional quantiles are:

$$Q(0.50)=(1-0.50)x_2+0.50x_3=0.50\times 2+0.50\times 3=2.5$$
$$Q(0.75)=(1-0.25)x_3+0.25x_4=0.75\times 3+0.25\times 4=3.25$$

These are also exactly the values where the boxplot boxes ended up being plotted. It should be noted that you drew up a pretty contrived example, drawing quartiles from $n=4$, but the formula should let you (re)calculate any quantiles of any sample.

If you're feeling adventurous you can even adapt the definitions of $j$ and $\gamma$ to other quantile types which is the `method` argument of `numpy.percentile`, though I'm quite sure this is not exposed in `seaborn`/`matplotlib`. The quantile definitions that result in $Q(0.25)=1.5$ as you seem to expect for this particular sample are H&F types 2 and 5.

The definition of the boxplot itself is really very standard and follows Tukey's original presentation, I'll just copy the [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) documentation here:

> The box extends from the first quartile (Q1) to the third quartile (Q3) of the data, with a line at the median. The whiskers extend from the box to the farthest data point lying within 1.5x the inter-quartile range (IQR) from the box. Flier points are those past the end of the whiskers.

```
     Q1-1.5IQR   Q1   median  Q3   Q3+1.5IQR
                  |-----:-----|
  o      |--------|     :     |--------|    o  o
                  |-----:-----|
flier             <----------->            fliers
                       IQR
```

Comment: Thank you. You wrote: "$X$ is the **population** quantile $P$ if: $\text{Pr}(x<X)\le P\ \text{and}\ \text{Pr}(x\le X)\ge P$". I think, as written, this is wrong. It should be "$x$ is the **population** quantile $P$ if: $\text{Pr}(X<x)\le P\ \text{and}\ \text{Pr}(X\le x)\ge P$".

Comment: How do you know that "`seaborn` calls `numpy.percentile` to draw its boxplots"? I'd like to know, because I intend to ask a follow-up question that relies on this assumption, so I need to be sure that it is based.

Comment: @EvanAad the notation was consistent there although not how it's usually written (I swapped variables and parameters), so I've modified it. For the second comment `seaborn` is just a wrapper around `matplotlib` - confirmed mainly through their documentation - and you can always look up [the source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/879bde7c3c653268884203207207d0b5600aa3d0/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py#L1284). Here I can also confirm you do *not* have control over `method`.

Comment: I'd say the definition here is a little backward as a quantile is a summary defined by the probability below and the complementary probability above (with as you say messy details on exactly what you do with data).  It's just common practice to use quantiles equally spaced on the probability scale. That is not part of the definition.  For example, min and max, 5 and 95% points and quartiles and median could be a useful summary set.